# Testing for Working Directory

Tags: powershell, scripting

My first steps were to create 2 variables and set their value to `args[0]` and `args[1]`, then have an `if` statement containing some error checking with `Write-Warning` and a `Read-Host` to capture user input and store the value in the variables.

Here is my code:

```
# Create 2 command line variables
$workingdirectory = ARGS[0]
$directoryname = ARGS[1]

## Check if variables are empty and get user input if necessary
if ("$workingdirecytory" -eq "") {
    Write-Warning "Parameter Required"
    $workingdirectory = Read-Host "Enter absolute path to working directory"
    Write-Warning "Parameter Required"
    $directoryname = Read-Host "Enter directory name to search for in $workingdirectory"
}
Write-Host "$workingdirectory"
Write-Host "$directoryname"
```

The question is:

> Write an if statement like this: `If (“$WorkingDirectory”  –eq “”) {`
>
> Inside the script blocks add the following:
>
> - use `Write-Warning` cmdlet to display a message “Parameter Required”
> - use `Read-host` to capture user input and store the value in the variable `$WorkingDirectory`
> - Repeat for DirectoryName

Am I suppose to have another `if` statement for the directory name?

Trying to make the output look like this:

[image: if statement output]

by:

- Now execute your code by typing the file name with no parameters
- Execute the code by typing the file name and one parameter
- Execute the code with the correct parameters

Comment: Yes, you need a second `if` statement for the directory name check.

Comment: awesome! I got it. Thanks : ]